# Parse url and choose specific number with php

Tags: php, rss

How is it possible to choose a specific word/s or number/s from a link with php. I have the following urls where I want to choose only the rss number. Have been trying to use preg_match and preg_replace to no avail unfortunately.

```
<link><![CDATA[http://www.domain.com/league/news/newsid=21898248704.html?rss=2148704+hakska+iwumao+oioqp+badge+water]]></link>

<link><![CDATA[http://www.domain.com/rugby/video/ball/index.html?rss=2133483+water+none+respective+all+sat's+report]]></link>
```

As you can see the urls are not the same but both have rss=XXXXXX.  My aim is to insert the number after "rss=" into the database.

Would appreciate if anyone can give me a tip of how to do this.

Comment: You want to get the value of the 'rss' param?

Comment: I would like to get the numbers after 'rss='.  Just that, nothing else.

E.g: rss=123456, rss=098765

I would like to get '123456' and '098765'. Unfortunately the urls were removed from my question.  Urls are completely different from one another so it's not something where I can preg_replace the url with nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this ?

```
<?php
$link = '<link><![CDATA[http://www.domain.com/league/news/newsid=21898248704.html?rss=2148704+hakska+iwumao+oioqp+badge+water]]></link>';

preg_match('/rss=([0-9]+)/', $link, $matches);

echo $matches[1]; // returns 2148704
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/foo.php?rss=9001+asdf";
$res = "";
$i = 0;
if (($i = strpos($url, 'rss=')) !== false) {
  $res = substr($url, $i + 4); // +4 because the length of 'rss=' is 4, we just want the value
  if (($i = strpos($res, '+')) !== false) { // $res contains +, cut that off
    $res = substr($res, 0, $i);
  }
  // res has a value
  echo $res;
} else {
  // res has no value
}
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b6279fa5673cadd7e1fe5d9eeb3b3c32f7c47645)

Answer (score 0):

$link = '';

preg_match('/rss=([0-9]+)/', $link, $matches);

echo $matches[1]; // returns 2148704

Worked fine.  Thanks a lot Phantom!